# How to combine three MySQL queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using a wordpress database we have tables like wp_options, and wp_postmeta.
These are grouped by primary key ID, then fields like 'option_name' and 'option_value';

So for example to find out three values I'd need to do 3 different queries.

**Is there a proper way to do all of this with only one query?**

Please shed some light on this and share the right way to do this.

```
SELECT option_value FROM bdlocal_wrdp1.wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl';

SELECT option_value FROM bdlocal_wrdp1.wp_options WHERE option_name='blogname';

SELECT option_value FROM bdlocal_wrdp1.wp_options WHERE option_name='blogdescription';
```

(returns example.com, Example Blog, This is an example blog.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT option_name,
       option_value
  FROM bdlocal_wrdp1.wp_options
 WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl', 'blogname', 'blogdescription')
```

And after this query execution you'll have 3 pairs of `option_name + option_value` values.

Comment: Thanks zerkms! This works so much better than what I was doing before.

Answer (score 3):

You can you `IN` clause for this,

```
SELECT option_value 
FROM bdlocal_wrdp1.wp_options 
WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl','blogname','blogdescription')
```

Comment: It will be tricky to know which value belongs to which option

Answer (score 1):

```
select (case when option_name='siteurl' then option_value else 0 end ) as 'siteurl',
   (case when option_name='blogname' then option_value else 0 end ) as 'blogname',
   (case when option_name='blogdescription' then option_value else 0 end ) as 'blogdescription' from bdlocal_wrdp1.wp_options
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use a **MySQL Union** for this functionality:

```
select option_name,option_value from wp_options where option_name='siteurl' UNION ALL
select option_name,option_value from wp_options where option_name='blogname' UNION ALL
select option_name,option_value from wp_options where option_name='blogdescription';
```

You can read more about Unions with some examples [here.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

Comment: Why did you choose this over `IN`? Your solution is guaranteed to be slower, 3 times longer and harder to read.

Comment: Well, a table with just millions of records is nothing for such a trivial query. If you checked the query plan you would see this query does more job. Have you checked the query plan already? What are the results? If no - what your assumption (?) is based on?

Comment: "The problem is that we have to run this check against every option_name in the table." --- that is wrong for sure.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for correcting me, I looked in to this and your method is  approximately twice as fast. You are very knowledgable and I appreciate you pointing this out!

Comment: I would suggest checking the `EXPLAIN` instead, just run times are not that representative.