# What's the proper way to combine these two queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select gmt from history.cachemap order by gmt asc limit 0,1;
..this returns gmt: 2012-05-03
select gmt from history.cachemap order by gmt desc limit 0,1;
..this returns gmt: 2012-09-15
```

A little background on the database I'm working with, I'm trying to get the earliest and latest date fields from a list of several million records.

Earlier this week I posted this question:

[How to combine three MySQL queries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469931/more-than-one-mysql-query)

This question was answered perfectly, but doesn't apply to this type of query.

Comment: You have a habit of asking questions with titles that aren't very descriptive, but with good titles in the body of the question. I've gone through and fixed this, but in the future it would be nice to just *put the descriptive title as the actual title*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use the max and min functions.  You can get the results as one row:

```
select min(gmt), max(gmt)
from history.cachemap
```

This is the most efficient solution, since it involves only one pass through the data.

Alternatively, you can put this into two rows, using union all:

```
select 'min' as which, min(gmt)
from history.cachemap union all
select 'max', max(gmt)
from history.cachemap
```

UNION/UNION ALL does not return rows in a specified order, so you should include information on which is which (or order them explicitly).

Comment: I have to accept this as the answer, you provided the best way of doing it in addition to teaching me how to use UNION ALL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(select gmt from history.cachemap order by gmt asc limit 0,1)
UNION
(select gmt from history.cachemap order by gmt desc limit 0,1)
```

Documentation: [UNION syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

Comment: Beat me by how much, 1/10th of a second!

Comment: @Cupidvogel 1 minute and 17 seconds, actually.

Comment: Right. But our approach is a bad one, the ones with the `min` and `max` are better. Dumb of me to not let that come to my mind.

Comment: Thanks! Learning UNION was hugely important to me. I have to select the MIN/MAX as the official answer, but this is what I really wanted to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    (select min(gmt) from history.cachemap),
    (select max(gmt) from history.cachemap)
```

Comment: Thanks! This teaches me how to combine just about any type of query.

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient way, but returning two columns instead of one, would be:

```
select MIN(gmt) AS mingmt, MAX(gmt) AS maxgmt
   FROM history.cachemap;
```

With indexing on `gmt`, in MySQL, it should be pretty much instantaneous.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about indexing. WOW what a speed difference!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single query as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(gmt), MAX(gmt) FROM history.cachemap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT GMT FROM HISTORY.CACEMAP ORDER BY GMT DESC LIMIT 0,1 UNION SELECT GMT FROM HISTORY.CACEMAP ORDER BY GMT ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: The ones with the `min` and `max` are better, use that.

Answer (score 0):

if history.cachemap contains millions of records (rows), it would be probably better with

```
SELECT gmt FROM history.cachemap WHERE gmt = max(gmt) OR gmt = min(gmt) ...
```

Something like that.. note, that with UNION you actually do the same query twice, to the same table, which contains million of records..